How to Achieve a Glassmorphic Background in Jetpack Compose Android?
play music
I'm trying to create a glassmorphic background effect in Jetpack Compose for my Android app. Specifically, I want a background that has a frosted glass effect with a blurred background while keeping the content on top sharp and clear.
Here's what I've tried so far:
Using Modifier.blur():
This blurs the entire content, including the text and images on top, which is not what I want.
Wrapping the background and content in different Box composables:
I attempted to apply the blur effect only to the background, but I still couldn't achieve the desired glassmorphic effect.
I'm looking for a way to create a background that looks like frosted glass with a blurred effect, but without blurring the content on top. Could someone guide me on how to achieve this in Jetpack Compose?

Use RenderEffect from Android 12+
In compose it would be something like this
Modifier.graphicsLayer(
    renderEffect = RenderEffect.createBlurEffect(25f,25f, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR).asComposeRenderEffect()
)


You can use chrisbanes' Haze library which implements the typical glassmorphism style with blurred, "frosted" background. Be aware though that it only works properly from Android 12 (API 32) on, since it is based on the RenderEffect API. For older Android versions it provides a simple fallback where the background remains unblurred.
